# Can any .NET type/interface be pattern matched as a list?

Tags: f#

I tried pattern matching .NET list types (e.g. `IList<>` and `List<>`):

```
match myIList with
| [] -> ...
```

I got an error saying `The expression was expected to have type IList<...> but here has type 'a list`. I get why it doesn't work - evidently, the types aren't compatible (I would guess that the F# list type does not implement `IList<>`).

What I'm wondering is, is there any BCL list types that can be pattern matched against without having to throw in a `Seq.toList` in the `match` expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the syntax used for constructing and deconstructing an F# list is defined specifically for that type, and that type only (those operators are actually used as case labels for `list` that get special treatment from the compiler). This is how the list type is defined in the core library:

```
type List<'T> = 
   | ([])  :                  'T list
   | (::)  : Head: 'T * Tail: 'T list -> 'T list
```

F# list is fundamentally different from `System.Collections.Generic.List` - it's a [cons list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons), and this nature is reflected in the syntax for construction/deconstruction.

`System.Collections.Generic.List` on the other hand is a collection that can grow in size, but is backed by an array and has the performance characteristics of an array - in fact its F# name (`ResizeArray`) is a far more fitting one.

`IList` is an interface for a mutable list, whereas F# list is immutable - it doesn't make sense for it to implement IList.

For both of those types - deconstructing them into head and tail in the same way it's done for F# lists simply doesn't reflect the reality of what they are, and would be an unnatural operation (much in the same fashion that indexing into an F# list is an unnatural operation).

Answer (score 3):

F# doesn't do automatic type coercion, like C# does. This means that you can't, for example, compare two values of different types, even if one of them is a subtype of the other.

```
let x : string = "abc"
let y : obj = box "abc"
let eq = x = y  // Type mismatch error here
```

Applying this to your specific case, you can't match a non-list value on a list, even if that value was somehow a subtype of list.

However, if you're really interested in this kind of matching, you could write yourself a custom matcher (also known as "[active pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns)"), which would take `seq<'t>` and match it with regular F# lists:

```
let (|IsList|) l = Seq.toList l
```

Such matcher is usable with anything that can be a `seq` - even, for example, a string:

```
match "abcd" with
| IsList [] -> "Empty string"
| IsList ('a'::_) -> "Starts with an a"
| IsList _ -> "Something else"
```

Works for normal lists, too:

```
match [1,2,3] with
| IsList [1,2,3] -> "One, two, three"
| IsList [] -> "Empty list"
| IsList _ -> "Huh?"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the bcl, I believe arrays are the only collection type that can be matched on without requiring `Seq.toList`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#array-pattern

```
let vectorLength vec =
    match vec with
    | [| var1 |] -> var1
    | [| var1; var2 |] -> sqrt (var1*var1 + var2*var2)
    | [| var1; var2; var3 |] -> sqrt (var1*var1 + var2*var2 + var3*var3)
    | _ -> failwith "vectorLength called with an unsupported array size of %d." (vec.Length)

printfn "%f" (vectorLength [| 1. |])
printfn "%f" (vectorLength [| 1.; 1. |])
printfn "%f" (vectorLength [| 1.; 1.; 1.; |])
printfn "%f" (vectorLength [| |] )
```